# Activating a function when file changes without the need for an infinite loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

It's difficult to explain what I've been trying to accomplish and my shallow knowledge does not allow me to resolve this doubt, for this reason I came here to ask for help.

I have an n1 program in python that performs a function if a txt file has its KB size equal to or greater than "1" and will not activate the function if the same file has its KB size equal to or less than "0". As you may know, the way to do this is very simple. However, this n1 program only knows if this file has changed if it performs this check. And to keep it constantly up to date I do an uninterrupted check with a loop:

```
#n1 program

import os

def functionInative() {
    #only activated if file KB == or > 1
}

while True:
    if os.stat(path-file).st_size > 0:
        functionIntive() # now activate functino

    else:
        pass
```

When the function is executed it will do its tasks and at the end it will clean the file so that if any new information arrives in the file, *it will be noticed and the process will be repeated*. For this reason I can't use something like a "break" either.

However, I wondered if it would be possible to let these programs somehow "stand still" and activate the function only when the file is filled. **No need for an infinite loop checking the file until there is any modification.**

It would be something like real-time PUSH or CHATS notifications. There is no free way a loop checking for new messages. It is simply only when they arrive that the functions are activated.

I hope you have understood my big question.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "an n1 program"? Are you perhaps looking for the something like the third-party Python library `watchdog` https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are asking about is a file watcher.

Your method of polling the file is fine actually. To avoid using up a lot of CPU cycles, you should probably add a `time.sleep(0.1)` call so that it is not checking nearly as often.

Although, Watchdog is a module in Python that will do exactly what you are asking and provide events that will call your function if a file changes.

Here is an example from their documentation:
https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/quickstart.html#a-simple-example

Comment: Great answer! A small code snippet is often better than links because links expire. You can either add the snippet from the link or create one that directly shows how to watch just a single file. Thanks again

Comment: I took a look at the link you sent and thank you very much for the response. However, I don't understand how this library can take advantage of simply using a "while True" with a "time.sleep(1)". After all, I noticed that the link script performs a "time.sleep" in a similar way. What I want is precisely to avoid this loop that demands CPU resources. I run more than 30 programs simultaneously and each one executes these loops, so you should already guess the sum total.

Comment: So the example in the link uses the time.sleep to check if the program should exit. It is not using that to check if the file is being used. The amount of CPU resources that is used executing this loop is very little and should not be an issue.

Comment: Thank you so much, Jacob! I performed tests without the loop and CPU utilization tests and really with the absence of the loop the usage is practically null. I still don't understand the magic that the "watchdog" library does to perform this observation without a loop but it evidently works and with very little use of resources.

Comment: @dogu the loop is necessary in order to keep the main thread running, and the sleep is necessary for catching keyboard events. Without the loop, the main thread dies and so does your program and watchdog; Without the sleep your program becomes unresponsive. As for how watchdog works, it is using different [os-specific APIs](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/api.html#watchdog.observers.Observer) under the hood. On linux for example, it uses [inotify](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) which is both a program and a library for getting notified about filesystem changes.

Comment: Thanks @smac89 for the working explanation. I certainly didn't notice the usefulness of the loop in the script. I will be taking a closer look at the functioning of the watchdog library to understand it better. Right now I'm happy that I won't have to use loops that check the file like the example I mentioned above. They were terrible in terms of performance, especially when I used them in more than 30 programs with "time.sleep(0.1)" haha! It was a veritable horde of checks.